# How to specify a dot separated table as a parameter into the sql query

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For purposes of this question, let's say there is a table schema `foo.bar.baz`

And we have created a cursor object using following boilerplate

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(...)
cur = ctx.cursor()
```

With that cursor object, we can put the whole dot deliminated schema into a query like so:

```
cur.execute('''
select * from foo.bar.baz
'''
)
```

and have no issues, but we wouldn't be able to do:

```
cur.execute('''
select * from %(tbl)s
''', {'tbl': 'foo.bar.baz'} 
)
```

Doing that throws this type of error: `ProgrammingError: 001011 (42601): SQL compilation error: invalid URL prefix found in: foo.bar.baz`

I'm guessing this is because the dots are sql identifiers and not strings, but I don't see any workaround in the snowflake documentation. Does anyone know how this could be done without having to change the connection object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html):

> In a FROM clause, the syntax **TABLE( { string_literal | session_variable | bind_variable } )** can be used

```
select * from TABLE(%(tbl)s)
```